# How do I rename a mysql table in php?

Tags: mysql, php, xampp, rename, sql

I have tried all sorts of things to get a table renamed from php, including mysqli (code below) and mysql_connect/mysql_query.    I have tried  rename table  and  alter table.
In the example below there are no errors when I execute it.   However, when I go look, the 'trac' table is still there with no '2' at the end.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("lamp1", "user", "pw", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "rename table trac to trac2")) {
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
else
 echo "error";
```

This is xampp (recent version) on a Windows Server 2008 machine.   Mysql 5.0.7, php 5.3.4.

I can rename the table with no issue through phpMyAdmin!

What can I check / try?   Is there a log file I can turn on / look at to see whats happening from the mysql side?

Comment: Are you getting "error" as a result of your script?  Throw a echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt); right after the execute (inside the if)

Comment: Well, ultimately mysqli_stmt_error($stmt); solved it for me.  I think between my different tests I may have had some 'table already exists' or other errors and now that I could see the errors, I was able to work it all out.  Ultimately my code above was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) to figure out the error that is being returned, and then act on that.

Answer (score 1):

citing from the MySQL manual

> When you execute RENAME, you cannot have any locked tables or active
>   transactions. You must also have the ALTER and DROP privileges on the
>   original table, and the CREATE and INSERT privileges on the new table.

So it is very likely that the user `user` does not have the correct privileges.